# Deal with name collitions between class and modules in Swift

Tags: swift, naming

We are having an issue with a name collision between a framework we are developing and one of its dependencies.

We have three things named `Foo`that are colliding:

- the dependency module
- a class in the dependency module
- a protocol in our module

Is there a way to import that module / class so we can use it?

We have tried `import class Foo.Foo` but doing this `Foo` still represents the protocol that's in our own module. And writing the dependency's type as `Foo.Foo` is not possible because the compiler complains that our protocol has no member named `Foo`...

Here is a base idea of what we would like to accomplish:

```swift
import class Foo.Foo

class Hello: OurModule.Foo { // Here Foo is our protocol

   var instance: Foo.Foo? // Here Foo.Foo is their class, compiler complains here

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do not ever ever give a module and a type the same name.

Comment: I agree... I learned my lesson some time ago but I have no control over the library I am using.